KQL for exfiltration of files/data ...almost there but slightly wrong
I'm trying to create a couple rules for the exfiltration of data based on files(and FileSize) using the tables DeviceNetworkEvents and DeviceFileEvents joined on InitiatingProcessAccountName.  (I don't have Sentinel or ADX to use some of the functions in those. )
My KQL to find a count of files sent out keeps giving me a flat line
DeviceNetworkEvents
| join kind=inner (DeviceFileEvents) on InitiatingProcessAccountName
| where FileName endswith ".docx" or FileName endswith ".pptx" or FileName endswith ".xlsx" or FileName endswith ".pdf" or FileName endswith ".txt" or FileName endswith ".zip"
// | distinct FileName, InitiatingProcessAccountName, Timestamp
| summarize FilesSent = dcount(FileName) by bin(Timestamp, 1d), InitiatingProcessAccountName
| render linechart


I'm trying to understand why this gives me a flat line across seven days, if I make a set of the files for the day with this KQL it's the exact same list everyday(which is obviously wrong)
|summarize FilesSent=make_set(FileName) by bin(Timestamp, 1d), InitiatingProcessAccountName

How do I get a different count each day? I'd appreciate the explanation, if possible.
Thank you!!
Referenced: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/blob/master/Hunting%20Queries/Microsoft%20365%20Defender/Exfiltration/detect-exfiltration-after-termination.yaml

What is the raw data? I mean, all I see in the graph is that the unique count of files sent is 15 a day. I can't tell whether that is right or not and without some sample data it is hard to tell what is going wrong.

@PeterBons, thank you for responding!  hmm, let me see about creating datatables with some fake data.  It should just be the same type of data in everyone's Advanced Hunting tables, but, it's a good exercise, let me see if I can create a couple fake datatables.

The query you provided, should not return a single flat line unless any of the following apply:

One or both of the tables are empty.
There is no data in the selected timeframe.
No process has interacted with any file ending with .docx, .pptx, .xslx, etc, within the selected timeframe.

After reproducing your query, I got a linechart with one line for each user. Unfortunately, however, the result of your query does not represent the count of files that were exfiltrated or uploaded to an online service.
DeviceNetworkEvents contains information about all network connections on a device and the processes that initiated these connections. (Initiating process details are only logged for outgoing connections for obvious reasons). This table does not contain information about the data that's being transferred over these connections or the requests that are being made. All it shows is things like remote IP, port numbers, protocol (UDP, TCP, ICMP, etc.).
DeviceFileEvents contains information about alterations to files on the system, i.e. files being created, modified, renamed, or deleted.
By performing an inner join on the InitiatingProcessAccountName, the query will return a set of data that merges the data from DeviceNetworkEvents and DeviceFileEvents. So if one user has 4.000 network events in 1 day and 2.500 file events (these are not unusual numbers), the merged result will contain 4.000 x 2.500 = 10.000.000 rows. Every row from the left table is linked to every row from the right table. Note that this does not mean that each network event relates to that file event. A better way to do this is to join on both the process ID and device ID. (different devices can use the same process ID, so only joining on process ID will result in network events from one device being linked up to file events from another device).
By doing this, however, it still doesn't give you information about files uploaded. It will only tell you for each process on each device what network connections it has made and what files it has created, modified, renamed or deleted.
Some things you can detect with Advanced Hunting are things like copying files to USB or network connections to online file sharing platforms like Google Drive or Dropbox. To effectively detect exfiltration of (sensitive) data, Microsoft has introduced solutions such as Purview and Defender for Cloud Apps
Sorry if this is a bit of an unsatisfactory answer, but I hope my explanation can help you find a solution for your problem.
